# How to number devices on a network?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to come up with a good scheme to setup devices on my network. I came up with this:

```
192.168.1.1 - Gateway
192.168.1.10 - Switch 1
192.168.1.11 - Switch 2 (if needed)
192.168.1.12 - Switch 3 (if needed)
192.168.1.20 - Wifi router 1
192.168.1.21 - Wifi router 2
192.168.1.30 - Server 1
192.168.1.31 - Server 2
192.168.1.40 - Printer 1
192.168.1.41 - Printer 2
192.168.1.42 - Printer 3
```

DHCP scope for workstations is usually located somewhere between 1.60 - 1.254 depending on number of hosts, etc.

This way I have spare IPs in each range if I need to add other devices, like more switches or printers.  I also have some extra room for security devices, camera feeds, etc.  I then lock off the users into a scope and it's all good.

I know some other people put their gateway/routers at .254 and start at the back and work down. I know ATT usually numbers their devices .254.

I'm wondering:

1. Are there just a few standard, recommended numbering conventions that are typically followed?  (If so, what are they?)
2. Is there any specific benefit of using one of those numbering plans?

Comment: OK thanks. I'm new here so still learning how it works. I guess this question won't work then because everyone has their own way of doing this. If someone answers and I think it's the best then it doesn't make it right. I'll think about how to re-word it

Comment: A "serving suggestion".  See how this flies and tweak if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with defining what a "good scheme" is? What are you trying to achieve in designing this scheme? Is it so that you can tell where a device is, or what type of device is might be... so on.

Depending on the size of your network, you can choose from class A (10.x.x.x) or class C (192.168.x.x) address ranges. From your example, it looks like a Class C range would suffice.

Common practice is to have the router/gateway address at either end of the range, mostly for convienience, but some routers have issues with their own IP being in the middle of the range.

Other than that, it's really up to the goals you wish to achieve with your scheme. If your goals was to segregate the range into "categories" then your example would work well.

Some might say you can even drill down further and lock workstations into specific scope, based on their location - for example, "1.100 -199" for 1st floor, "1.200-250" for 2nd floor... etc.

I personally have all the "non-workstations" devices like router/servers, printers numbered from 1 to 20 and match them to the switch ports, that way I can tell whether a particular device is physically connected, when troubleshooting.

At the end of the day, whatever scheme you choose, just make sure you are consistent with it. And communicate/document it clearly, for the benefit of your colleagues and/or your future self :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, some useful tips there. I love the idea of matching devices up to their port number, that is really useful. Thank you!